# valueChanges is fired but nothing is selected

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm new to angular, and encountered a weird phenomenon.
I've a form with custom material multi select component which has an extra 'All' option to select/deselect all options, selected by default at startup of the component. Once the form has been submitted, it's value is saved in the store (NgRx), and then patched to the form when back from the result component. The formControl of the select component has the exact patched value but nothing is selected in this component. The value is still in formControl, and it works when I re submit the form...

Here is the valueChanges of the custom select component :

```
this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroy$),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
).subscribe(
  (next: SelectOption[]) => {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();

    if (next) {

      let toSelectAll: boolean = JSON.stringify(next) === JSON.stringify(this.options);

      if (this.all && toSelectAll && ignoreValueChanges == false) {
        this.allMatOption.select();
        if (next.indexOf(this.allSelectOption) < 0) {
          next.push(this.allSelectOption);
          ignoreValueChanges = true;
          this.control.setValue(next);
        }
      }
      ignoreValueChanges = false;
      this.control.setValue(next);
      this.selectedChips = this.filteredOptions(next);
      // this.control.updateValueAndValidity();
      this.logger.debug('[' + this.inputLabel + '] valueChanges\n', this.control.value);
    }
  }
);
```

The value from NgRx effect :

```
  private initOptions(): void {

this.travelOptionsStore.dispatch(new FetchTravelOptions());
this.travelOptionsStore.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroy$),
  select(fromTravelOptionSelector.optionsSelector)).subscribe(
    next => {
      if (next) {

        const configOptions: SelectOption[] = this.isMode() ?
          Object.values(this.rsConfig.modesOptions) :
          Object.values(this.rsConfig.networksOptions);

        const travelOptions: TravelOption[] = this.isMode() ? next.modes : next.networks;

        let fetchedOptions: SelectOption[] = (travelOptions && travelOptions.length > 0) ?
          travelOptions.map(option => new SelectOption(option.key, option.name)) : configOptions;

        this.options = fetchedOptions;

        if (this.control.value) {
          this.logger.log('[' + this.inputLabel + '] initOptions :\n', value);

        } else {

          // Patch control value only the very first time.
          if (this.all && this.options && this.allMatOption) {
            this.control.setValue([...this.options]);
          }

        }
      }
    },
    error => { this.logger.error(error) }
  );
```

}

The template :

```html
<mat-form-field fxFlex>
  <mat-label>{{ inputLabel }}</mat-label>
  <mat-select
    [formControl]="control"
    [placeholder]="placeholder"
    (selectionChange)="selectionChanged($event)"
    multiple
  >
    <mat-select-trigger>
      <mat-chip-list>
        <mat-chip
          *ngFor="let option of this.selectedChips"
          removable="true"
          (removed)="remove(option)"
        >
          {{ option.label }}
          <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
      </mat-chip-list>
    </mat-select-trigger>

    <mat-option
      *ngIf="all"
      #allOption
      (click)="toggleAllSelection()"
      [value]="allSelectOption"
    >
      {{ allSelectOption.label }}
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let option of options"
      [value]="option"
      (click)="togglePerOne()"
    >
      {{ option.label }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here is versions installed :

```
"@angular/core": "~10.1.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^10.0.0",
"@angular/common": "~10.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~10.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "~10.1.0",

"@ngrx/effects": "^9.2.0",
"@ngrx/router-store": "^9.2.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^9.2.0",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^9.2.0",
"rxjs": "~6.5.4",

"@angular/cli": "~10.1.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.0",
```

The other fields are patched without problem.
I'm desperate, being stuck for several days on it without any solution. If anyone has an idea?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of research, I finally found out the problem!
At moment of 'writeValue(obj)', the formControl compare every value with all options. But when the value and options are custom objects (class), it compare the 'reference' and not the value. To fix it, I had to add compareWith directive in template :

```
  <mat-select
    [formControl]="control"
    [placeholder]="placeholder"
    (selectionChange)="onSelectionChanged($event)"
    [(compareWith)]="compareFn"
    multiple
  >
```

and the compareFn in component :

```
  public compareFn(s1: SelectOption, s2: SelectOption) {
    return s1 && s2 && s1.key === s2.key;
  }
```

Now it works perfectly.